# How to view socket(7) manual on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am reading "Foundations of python network programming."

It asks me to view socket(7) manual.

I tried

```
man socket
```

It shows me socket(2)

And when I type

```
man socket(7)
```

It says wrong command.

How can I view socket(7)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is man [section] topic so

`man 7 socket`

Comment: As a side note, you can learn the syntax of the `man` command by using the command `man man`.